# PHP - Use range() as value for Array

Tags: php, arrays, range

I've seen a few example here on stack but they don't seem to cover this scenario.

I'm attempting this;

```
$flight_range = array(
                    array('range' => range(1,50),  'service' => 'Long Haul'),
                    array('range' => range(51,54), 'service' => 'Short Haul'),
                    ....
                 );
```

but PHP won't let me. It returns;

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ')' on line 02
```

This does not work either;

```
array(range(1,50), range(51,54) ...
```

The problem is with trying to assign a value of range().

I have 20+ sets of range values to assign.

Can anyone suggest an easy method for achieving these sorts of array values?

EDIT;
haike00, Jack and Sean are right.

Maybe my question should be how do i make $flight_range a member variable of a class;

```
private $flight_range = array(array('range' => range(1,50), 'service' => 'Long Haul'));
```

Comment: Is this array declared at the very top of your script? It does not look like this is where the error lies. Try making only this array in a new script and do a print_r again.

Comment: There's no problem with [your code](http://codepad.viper-7.com/74gqau).

Comment: There must be another issue in your script. Your posted code works - see this phpfiddle - http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/sfb-6v6

Comment: go to the line where the error occurs according to parsing error.. then copy/paste that line here. Those `....` does not help much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the problem with doing this in your constructor?

```
class MyClass {
        private $flight_range;

        public function __construct() {
                $this->flight_range = array(
                        array(
                                'range' => range( 1, 50 ),
                                'service' => 'Long Haul'
                        )
                );
        }
}
```

Comment: Nothing. Thanks Jacob. I was assigning values to the members in their declaration.

    class my_class {

        private $flight_range = 'blah blah';

        public function __construct() {
            ...  do some contruct stuff here ...
        }
    }

Seems that doesn't work in this case.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

Its working fine on my end.

```
$flight_range = array(
               array('range' => range(1,50) ,  'service' => 'Long Haul'),                 array('range' => range(51,54),'service' => 'Short Haul'));

 print_r($flight_range);
```

Just copy and paste above code and run it.

Comment: This should be a comment. And there are at least two comments that say the same thing.